# How do I make an option for each user to change color of WordPress site?

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, customization, profile

I want to provide an option for each user to specify their own color to show on the site.  So they would go to their profile page on the front end of the site and use a color picker to define a custom color code (e.g. #ff0000).

I don't need to know how to setup the color picker, just how to make a user profile option effect the stylesheet for that logged in user.

Comment: Maybe [this article](http://humanos.uci.cu/2014/03/humancode-personaliza-el-menu-de-wordpress/) gives you an idea (spanish and for WordPress sites, but the idea is the same for another scenario). You can see the solution working on the same site ;)

Answer (score 0):

you may add classes to the body in php and relate color scheme to that class like this:

```
<body class="blue"><!-- or red or green -->
```

and in your css:

```
body.blue .sidebar{ background-color: #0000ff; color: #efefef}
body.red .sidebar{ background-color: #ff0000; color: #efefef}
body.green .sidebar{ background-color: #00ff00; color: #efefef}
```